# Alternative ways to change integer array to a string (without commas)

Tags: python

I have the following array:

```
sum_list = [30, 70, 110]
```

I used

```
print(str(sum_list).strip('[]').replace(",", ""))
```

This does the job but is there another (shorter) method?

Comment: Iterate over the list, appending elements to a string as you do so.

Comment: `' '.join(str(i) for i in sum_list)`

Comment: Thanks guys! Much appreciated!

Comment: You just want `print(*sum_list)` if all you want to do is print it. If you want the actual string, just `" ".join(map(str, sum_list))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
print(" ".join(map(str,sum_list)))
```

Or even:

```
print(*sum_list)
```

Comment: print(*sum_list) is beautiful.

Comment: I don't think the OP wan'ts `""` as a separator, but a single space, i.e. `" "`

Comment: I didn't think concatenation made sense, but I had misread the question/other solutions.  Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
"".join(str(val) for val in sum_list)
```